# how to send a nat value other than a whole number

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, michelson, fa1.2

How can I send a `nat` value to a contract that represents a data type which is not a whole number?

For example, [the `xtzToToken` entrypoint of the tzBTC contract](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/entrypoints) allows a user to call the `xtzToToken` entrypoint and send an argument of `nat minTokensBought`. If I want to send a value that is between 1 and 0 for this argument, how would I do so>

Here is what I've tried (unsuccessfully) via the tezos=client:

```
tezos-client --dry-run transfer 10000 from alice to KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5 \
                --entrypoint xtzToToken \
                --arg '(Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" (Pair 1/2 "2021-09-01T09:57:00Z"))' \
                --burn-cap 999
```

and

```
tezos-client --dry-run transfer 10000 from alice to KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5 \
                --entrypoint xtzToToken \
                --arg '(Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" (Pair 0.5 "2021-09-01T09:57:00Z"))' \
                --burn-cap 999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to send lower than 1 mutez. `nat` is also required to be a whole number.

Tezos/XTZ has 6 decimal places. When a user sees "1 XTZ" in an app, that is represented as 1000000 on the blockchain (6 zeros for 6 decimal places). The blockchain and RPC deal in this smaller scale (called mutez) and its up to each application to scale it up to XTZ when displaying to a user.

It is the same for all tokens. tzBTC has 8 decimal places, so 1 tzBTC, is made up of 100000000 satoshi's.

When you are doing this:

```
(Pair 1 "2021-09-01T09:57:00Z")
```

you are not sending 1 XTZ, you are sending 1 mutez (1/1000000 of an XTZ). Sending 1 XTZ would look like this:

```
(Pair 1000000 "2021-09-01T09:57:00Z")
```

Comment: So if I want to send a .62 value for ```minTokensBought``` to the ```addLiquidity``` entrypoint, I would send a value of (.62 * 100000000) or 62000000? Also, how can I look at a contracts code on an explorer like tzkt.io to see the amount of decimal places that token uses?

Comment: Also it may be worth calling out that the argument I'm passing isn't a value for tzBTC, it's a value for the LQT token found here: https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1AafHA1C1vk959wvHWBispY9Y2f3fxBUUo/operations/

Comment: @Whirlybird Fa1.2 tokens have no standard way to record decimal places, typically you check their website. FA2 contracts have a metadata field thats stored offchain and holds this info. The Better Call dev explorer manually indexes token data. If you search for a contract and click on the "Tokens" tab you can see the metadata. Here for example is Ethtz, where you can see that it has 18 decimal places: https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT19at7rQUvyjxnZ2fBv7D9zc8rkyG7gAoU8/tokens